# Extraction of the word from string knowing the index of the one character inside the word (python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, extract

I'm using `diff_match_patch` method called `match_main` to find a best match of for example invoice number in a list of available invoice numbers if the user provides the number in different format (order, separators)

`match_main` returns an `index`, for example if the pattern is **`20170630/4072/00`** and the list of possible invoice numbers is a string **`20180923-5032-02 2016-6872-01 20170630-4072-00 20170620-4072-00 20091204-7914-00`** (so invoice numbers with space as a separator) it will return 30 (index of the first character from 'correct' number which is **`20170630-4072-00`** and I know how to extract that number automatically (I know the index of the first character of the number and I know it ends before the next space) but if the user provides invoice number but in different order (**`4072-00-20170630`**) it will return 39 and that's in the middle of 'correct' number and in this case I don't know how to extract that number (I know the index of the character somewhere inside the number and that the number begins after last space and ends before the next space)

Comment: You should parse the invoce number provided to match your pattern first. Split it into the 3 desired numbers and return it in the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you need to do is find the last separator character to the left of the character returned by match_main, and the first separator to the right of that character. If so, something like this should work:

```
about_here = match_main(mystery_text, invoice, 0)
left_sep = mystery_text.rfind(' ', 0, about_here) + 1
right_sep = mystery_text.find(' ', about_here)
my_invoice = mystery_text[left_sep:right_sep]
```

This assumes that your separator is always a space. You'll also need to check boundary conditions: if your invoice is at the start or the end of the string, `rfind` and `find` will return -1. Is this approximately what you were looking for?

BTW, Sergio sugests to split the string up front and then do the matching. He is right, but I'm assuming you are dealing with a very long input string (since you're using dif-match-patch) and don't want to create a large array just to fin your number.